# Too much vertical space between table rows in IE

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am making an order form in HTML and jQuery. There are some parameters the customer must specify before he can press the *Add to shopping list* button. When the button is pressed, I have a function `AddToBasket` that extracts the parameters the customer has selected, and then appends a row to the shopping list.

This works fine in Chrome, Opera and Firefox, but by some reason IE adds a lot of vertical space around each row. Each row contains a descriptive text that typically contains two line feeds/breaks. As mentioned, these appears nicely below each other in most browsers, but in IE there's so much vertical space around each row, so I can't fully see two rows in the list at the same time.

My shopping list is an HTML table that is 220 pixels tall, and 450 wide. Here is the code for the table (I've wrapped it in a div):

```
<div style="height:220px;width:450px;font:16px Courier New, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;border:2px solid #7AB800">
  <table width="100%" height=30px cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="orderlist">
    <thead>
      <tr style="color:#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#7AB800">
        <th align="left" width="80">
          DELETE
        </th>
        <th align="left" width="80">
          NUMBER
        </th>
        <th align="left">
          DESCRIPTION
        </th>
        <th class="colMeterType">
           Meter type
        </th>
        <th class="colModuleType">
           Module type
        </th>
        <th class="colOrderOrQuote"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="shoppingListBody" style="height:200px;">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Only the first three columns are visible, colMeterType, colModuleType and colOrderOrQuote are set to be invisible in the css styling. Here I store info that the user doesn't need to see. When the user presses the add to basket button, I call a function where I first extract the variables the user has selected, then appends it to the shoppinglist:

```
  $('#orderlist').append('<tr>'+
    '<td align="center" class="rm"><input type="checkbox"/></td>'+
    '<td><input class="numberOfItems" value="1" width="75px" size="3" pattern="[0-9]+" onkeyup="verifyQuantity()" type="text"/></td>'+
    '<td>'+bodyContent +"</td>"+
    '<td class="colMeterType">'+txtMeterType +"</td>"+
    '<td class="colModuleType">'+txtModuleType+ "</td>"+
    '<td class="colOrderOrQuote">'+ txtOrderOrQuote + "</td></tr>");
```

The descriptive text is stored in the variable `bodyContent`.

The CSS doesn't contain much at all, but here it is:

```
<style type="text/css">
   .HMalternatives{margin-left:20px;}
   .COMalternatives{margin-left:20px;}
   .colMeterType{display:none;}
   .colModuleType{display:none;}
   .colBestEllerForesp{display:none;}
   .warning{background-color:red;}
   .clear{ cleear:both; line-height: 0; overflow:hidden;}
   hr { border:0; border-top: 2px solid #7AB800 !important; height:0; width:100%; }
</style>
```

I have searched both Stack  Overflow and other places for a solution to this. I couldn't find anyone with my exact problem, but I've tried different stuff like setting `tr { padding-bottom:0px}` in the styling, but nothing of what I've found solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to say without testing the exact HTML/CSS myself.

But, I would recommend checking the padding and margin settings for any and all elements within the table cells - input elements and the like. Also the line-height of text within cells will affect the row height, as well as having padding on top of a height attribute. If you have a sample of the final HTML plus CSS it might be easier to test out.

Comment: As far as I can see I've provided all the code that has anything to do with the table/shopping list. I haven't added any padding to the elements that I add to the shopping list, i.e. a row containing a checkbox, a textbox and some plain text. Just now I added style="padding: 0px;" to the td's containing the checkbox and the textbox, still I get a lot of vertical space in IE.

Comment: @Dibya - Why should this be a comment? I provided an answer. The style of elements within the cells is the most likely problem. Sorin - the CSS for all the classes defined here is not apparent. These are a likely culprit.

Comment: @Sorin What ever you suggest it must lead the OP to a solution. I can tell you the best answer for any question is **GOOGLE**. We don't an answer if we are not sure what answers should be. Please avoid answering if you are not sure.